# How to prevent indexing of content from CelerySearchIndex

Tags: django, django-haystack, django-celery

I have a model that looks like this in part:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My search index inherits from CelerySearchIndex:

```
class ContentIndex(celery_haystack_indexes.CelerySearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
```

When `SearchIndex` gets called on `Content.save()`, I *do not* want this content indexed.  I expect unpublished Content on my site to go through a lot of revisions, so there would be a huge performance hit of wasted calls to Solr.  However, nothing in the documentation seems to work.

I tried:

```
def should_update(self, content):
    if content.published and content.public:
        return True
    return False
```

I also tried hooking into `update_object()`.

In neither case did either routine even get called.

Anyone know how to do this???  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#SearchIndex.should_update), there appears to be **kwargs passed to should_update that you're missing in your method signature. Maybe try adding that?

Comment: But should_updated() isn't even getting called.  The problem is further upstream.